# Invalid Toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 10.2 Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13 or later.

Comment: any one can help? Xcode had updated to 10.2.

Comment: Sounds like Apple forget to flip a switch. You sould file a radar.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I've updated to latest stable releases of Mojave and Xcode, but also keep getting these annoying messages from Team Apple.

Btw, I found two solutions:
• delete Xcode and move back manually to previous version (which is 10.1 now)
• manually change some config files to fool the review process (Apple will think that you're using old Xcode and/or old macOS)

---

Update:
I asked many experienced developers about that and all of them said "just wait".

------—

Update 2 (27.03.2019):
AppStore took a dump so everything now seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Xcode to 10.1 helped me

1. Go https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
2. Find and download Xcode 10.1.
3. Double-click to unpack.
4. Remove old Xcode from Applications and paste this one instead.
5. Build your artifact